# C++ tree output error

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

for my data structures class, we are making a data structure that we can use to easily store and organize data. I am having an issue with the output function of my tree. The error message that I get is:

```
AccountDB.cpp: In member function ‘void AccountDB::output(std::ostream&) const’:
AccountDB.cpp:23:21: error: passing ‘const AccountDB’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void    
AccountDB::output(std::ostream&, const AccountDB::Elem*)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I've been looking around and my output code looks pretty similar to what other people have done. I have no idea, and I don't really understand what the error is trying to tell.

Thanks for your help.

**Header:**

```
#ifndef ACCOUNTDB_H
#define ACCOUNTDB_H


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


#include "AccountRecord.h"

class AccountDB {

public:
    AccountDB();
    ~AccountDB();
    void insert( const AccountRecord &v );
    AccountRecord * get( const AccountRecord &v );
    void output( ostream &s ) const;

private:
    struct Elem {
        AccountRecord info;
        Elem *left;
        Elem *right;
    };

Elem *root;

void insert( const AccountRecord &v, Elem *&e );
AccountRecord * get( const AccountRecord &v, Elem *&e );
void output( ostream &s, const Elem *e );

};

ostream &operator << ( ostream &s, const AccountDB &v );

#endif
```

**Source**

```
#include "AccountDB.h"

//default constructor
AccountDB::AccountDB() {
    root = 0;
}

//destructor
AccountDB::~AccountDB() {

}

//public
void AccountDB::insert( const AccountRecord &v ) {
    return insert( v, root );
}

AccountRecord * AccountDB::get( const AccountRecord &v ) {
    return get( v, root );
}

void AccountDB::output( ostream &s ) const {
    output( s, root );
}

//private
void AccountDB::insert( const AccountRecord &v, Elem *&e ) {
    if( e == NULL ) {
        e = new Elem();
        e->info = v;
    }

    else if( v < e->info )
        insert( v, e->left );
    else if( v > e->info )
        insert( v, e->right );
}

AccountRecord * AccountDB::get( const AccountRecord &v, Elem *&e ){
    if( e->info == v )
        return &(e->info);
    else if( v < e->info && e->left != NULL )
        get( v, e->left );
    else if( v > e->info && e->right != NULL )
        get( v, e-> right );
    else
        return NULL;
}

void AccountDB::output( ostream &s, const Elem *e ) {

    if( e != NULL ) {
        output( s, e->left );
        s << e->info << endl;
        output( s, e->right );
    }
}

ostream &operator << ( ostream &s, const AccountDB &v ) {
    v.output( s );
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `output` function is not declared `const`, so when you call

```
output( s, root );
```

the compiler tells you that you are calling a non-const function from inside a `const` function.

There are several ways to deal with this - one is to make `output` const; the other is to make `output` static (if you can).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yeah, I know, I'm a slow typist :(

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to make it static. He actually can and should.

Comment: Heh, you guess still beat me when I was just about to post the answer.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, what is the advantage of using static instead?

Comment: @David Generally, it is a good idea to use `static` functions to indicate their logical independence of the *instance*. This conveys your intent to human readers of your programs. Less importantly, you can save some CPU cycles by not passing the hidden *"this"* pointer to your functions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight const, static etc. littered all over can make code nigh-unreadable. It is largely a stylistic choice. It has its places but not everywhere. Furthermore "saving a few CPU cycles not passing a this pointer" is rather silly. The compiler will optimize it as static if it doesn't reference class variables anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that

```
void AccountDB::output( ostream &s, const Elem *e )
```

is not declared as `const`, but you call it from a `const` method.

Change the declaration (and definition) to:

```
void output( ostream &s, const Elem *e ) const;
```

You can do this since you're not modifying any members inside the function.